# Slow ADC to take samples of a fast-changing signal

Tags: adc, sample-and-hold

The context is *more or less* as follows (this relates to a research project in early stages, so I cannot disclose all the details):

I have a signal with potentially very high slew-rate, in the order of 10 or 20 Volts/ns. Once in a while (say, no more than once every few milliseconds), I need to take five samples of that signal, about 100 or 200 ps apart (i.e., at the equivalent of a 10 or 5 Gsps sampling rate).

In principle, I could put five cheap ADCs (even ADCs as slow as 1ksps would do);  except that the signal is changing too fast, so the conversion may be disrupted / distorted, and samples at contiguous time points may not show the relevant difference that I need to capture. Even if I go to ADCs in the order of several hundred Msps (with built-in S/H), their specified aperture delay is in the order of 1ns.

Looking for S&H amplifiers, for example at Analog Devices, the best I can find is 250ns acquisition time. Renesas' HA5351 specifies 70ns acquisition time — still too slow.

Am I missing some obvious alternative?  (other than just going with an ultra-fast ADC in the order of tens of Gsps?)

Perhaps the more obvious question: should I expect those ADCs with 1ns aperture to still work?  The sample may be distorted, but if the distortion is consistent, it might still work:  I am sampling the analog voltage during a 1ns window, and 200ps later sample again in during a different (shifted) 1ns window.  (using five of those relatively pricey ADCs is not ideal;  but I think it's still substantially cheaper than one ADC at tens of Gsps)

Comment: Is it random ? like a Partial Discharge (PD)?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't want to take this on.  You'll spend more time and expense validating your methods than collecting real data.  You don't list the details of your workflow, but if it's amenable to your process, I would consider using a high bandwidth oscilloscope with a good SDK, and suck the data into a computer.

Comment: I think you're probably looking at the wrong thing if you're finding S&H limited to 250ns (1-2 ns is common and I see various options from AD), but that still doesn't help you get to 200 ps.  Is buying a commercial DAQ an option?  There are companies that specialize in this that are widely used for research applications, which sounds like what you're doing.  What analog bandwidth (not just sampling rate) do you need?

Comment: I think there are better methods but we need to know the details. Impedance vs Voltage vs time vs tolerance error, Are you wanting to capture energy, charge , voltage , delay, negative resistance, hysteresis effects ?

Comment: Perhaps cheaper/easier than 5 fast ADCs is 5 fast S/Hs, with their outputs multiplexed into a single modest speed ADC. Agree with other commenter that faster S/Hs ought to be possible to find. If not, a GHz schottky diode mixer driven by a pulse on the LO is a fast switch between RF and IF, and you can build your own S/Hs.

Comment: Fast ADC's must be 50 Ohms or so and your signal impedance is undefined and a good TEK DSO might run over 100k$ or $10k/mo

Comment: insufficient data on trigger and signal impedance

Comment: @user1850479 ‒ you write "_1-2 ns is common and I see various options from AD_" ... I seem to be missing something .... this is the "Sample/Track and Hold Amplifiers" parametric search page I find at AD: https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11071# — fastest options are the AD783, 250ns, and then the AD781 at 700ns).  I agree that this does not sound right (it made no sense whatsoever to me when I first found this info, that the fastest SHA would have a lousy 250ns acquisition time.

Comment: The AD783 is a 100 KHz ADC, so you're probably looking at low frequency catalog. Try the high speed ADC page instead.

Comment: This is reminding me of some episode of "The Twilight Zone", where we are in alternate universes yet communicating through this forum .... How is the AD783 a 100kHz ADC?? — https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad783.html, description reads: _High Speed, Monolithic Sample-and-Hold Amplifier_.  It _does say_ high-speed, although 250ns seems laughable by comparison to modern high-speed ADCs with their built-in S&H